# SQL Server RAM usage is increasing and query executions is slowing down with time

Tags: sql-server, memory, wait-types

I'm using SQL server on a server with 48 GB of RAM.

When I start the SQL Server service, it's using 12% of the RAM at first, but after 24 hours it's reaching 90% and query executions begin slowing down. We have to restart the service so we can serve users.

What could be the problem and how we can fix it?

Example images:

[image]

[image]

and 
(select value_in_use from sys.configurations where name = 'max degree of parallelism')

[image]

and my server cores are 47.

Comment: SQL Server will use all the ram available. Just limit the max in the settings. For the performances you need to investicate furter. What is consuming resources in your database? How many running sessions? Activity monitor adn query store are good starting point.

Comment: Please update your question with the result of the query from this link: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/wait-statistics-or-please-tell-me-where-it-hurts/

Comment: @sepupic I upload result.

Comment: Here is the script to see what types of LATCHes do you have: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/most-common-latch-classes-and-what-they-mean/ please add the result of this too

Comment: Your instance has enough memory and your problem is not there. Maybe you have wrong parallelism settings, but please first show us the result of detailed latches wait stats

Comment: @sepupic I upload new results.

Comment: Yes your latches waits has to do with parallelism. What is yout full server version (select @@version), max dop of parallelism on server level (select value_in_use
from sys.configurations
where name = 'max degree of parallelism') and number of processors(cores) on your server?

Comment: @sepupic @@version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2) (KB4052908) - 13.0.5026.0 (X64)   Mar 18 2018 09:11:49   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)  and i upload result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the `waits statistics` in your system you have incorrect settings for `parallelism`.

`Maxdop` in your system should not be more than `16`, you can find the correct value based on this MS article: [Recommendations and guidelines for the "max degree of parallelism" configuration option in SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2806535/recommendations-and-guidelines-for-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-confi)

Here are some T-SQL scripts to do it (I don't know your exact `NUMA` configuration but the scripts alilyze it):
[MAXDOP setting algorithm for SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36522/maxdop-setting-algorithm-for-sql-server)

Here is the explanation given by **Max Vernon** on which I agree. He explains why incorrect setting of `maxdop` slows down the execution.

> If you set MAXDOP higher than the number of cores/numa node, you end
>   up with calls into far memory which are many many times slower than
>   calling near memory. This is because each numa node has its own
>   memory; having a query use more threads than are present in a single
>   numa mode will spread the CPU load over multiple cores, and therefore
>   multiple memory nodes.

Answer (score 2):

SQL will always use up the RAM it has to cache data.
Setting a min/max RAM for your instance is always a good idea (especially MAX, so you keep some RAM for your OS)
See this good answer on dba.SE:[Why is SQL Server consuming more server memory?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/why-is-sql-server-consuming-more-server-memory)

Right click your instance in SSMS -> Memory -> Fill in min/max memory. It's a good idea to leave at least 4 GB for your OS on a SQL dedicated machine. If you have other services running, keep those in mind as well.

Now, you're saying your queries are slowing down, which should not happen. Perhaps you should make a different question asking for performance advice on specific queries.

Comment: I think to [Enable the Lock Pages in Memory Option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/enable-the-lock-pages-in-memory-option-windows?view=sql-server-ver15) additionally to configuring the min/max RAM settings would be a good idea.